# Finding Web Application Average Load Times

Tags: html, performance, web, performance-testing

I am trying to find out the average time it takes various pages of a (private) web application for different users in remote locations. I know I can use Chrome Developer Tools, YSlow etc. To find out how long the page loads. However this requires me to manually test etc. record averages (as far as I know)

Does anyone know any Windows based application/plugin that would let me run say 20 page loads and find out the average. Ideally I would like to do this for a whole user session, just get the user to browse over a given period and the average page loads could be calcualated. Ideally I'd like to be able to see the same page averages and the average for the whole site. Any ideas? Anything vageuly similar would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a tool like JMeter to load test and capture your results.

It can be used to simulate a heavy load on a server, network or object to test its strength or to analyze overall performance under different load types. You can use it to make a graphical analysis of performance or to test your server/script/object behavior under heavy concurrent load.

http://jmeter.apache.org/

Comment: I'd heard of JMeter I thought it was more for creating load rather than actually recording the results etc. Will look into it. Thanks

Comment: It does test and record the results.

Comment: Great thanks. Well on my way to setting up some basic tests already!

Comment: @GraemeMiller ty :-) it sure is an awesome tool!!