# How to test the ASP.NET (with MVC 3) application after implemented the OutputCache?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, performance-testing

I have implemented recently into my ASP.NET application the OutputCache.

I want to test this application by accessing 100-200 times simultaneously to see if the cache make good job.

I have installed [RedGate .NET Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) and [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) to see what's happens with cache. I see that cache occupies some size in memory and page loads faster than before implementing cache (that's normal).

Can you tell me what tools I need to test my ASP.NET MVC3 application by being accessed  100-200 times simultaneously ? Something like `server stress test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right you want to stress test your website? You can take a look at [Web Capacity Analysis Tool (WCAT)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231282)

Also take a look at this website http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2008/05/05/asp-net-performance-engineering-stress-test-your-architecture-design-and-code.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: I googled too for my question and I found `Web Performance Test` but it exists only in Ultimate version of Visual Studio. I have professional :(

Comment: @SnakeEyes take a loot at [this website ](http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2007/05/wcat-63-(x64)) WCAT is free. You don't have to pay for VS ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) . It is a great stress tool and we use it to test our .Net applications performance on Windows Azure. JMeter is one of the most popular stress testing tools that there is.

You can write scripts that navigate to certain pages, and authenticate and do posts etc. Therefore you could simulate 200 connections to the page site and see what effect that has on memory usage etc. Obviously once you have made a script it is easy to re-run so it will give you a base-line for consistent analysis. You can keep historic logs and see if your changes are improving load-times etc.

It can start many connections and then give you detailed performance reports on load times as well. It is very easy to use.

I had a question about performance testing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234907/finding-web-application-average-load-times)